# Templates files for custom post type with custom tags

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, template-hierarchy, register-taxonomy

There is a task: Create a new post type (`video`) with its own post tags and tag page - separate from normal post.

What I've done:

```
// Create a new post type
register_post_type('video',
    array('labels' => array('name' => 'videos', 'menu_name' => 'Видео', 'singular_name' => 'video', 'add_new' => 'Добавить видео'),
    'public' => true, 'has_archive' => true, 'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt3', 'supports' => array('title')
));

// Create its own new post tag
function video_tag_taxonomy() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Video Tag',
        'singular_name'              => 'Video Tag',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Метки',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Video Tags',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Video Tag',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Video Tag:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Video Tag',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Добавить новую метку',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Video Tag',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Video Tag',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Метки разделяются запятыми',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Video Tags',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Video Tags',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Выбрать из часто используемых меток',
        'not_found'                  => 'Not Found',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy('video_tag', array( 'video'), $args );

}

add_action( 'init', 'video_tag_taxonomy', 0 );
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'video_tag', 'video' );
```

The problem: if I click one of the new tags, I move on: site.com/video_tag/my_tag_name

But it's an archive page template. And I couldn't create a separate template. I've tried `tags-video_tag.php`, `archive-video.php` but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to create `taxonomy.php` or `taxonomy-video_tag.php` which should be the templates to use to display your custom taxonomy term archives on. You should have a look at the [taxonomy term archive hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies)

Just remember to flush your permalinks in case

Comment: Pieter, thanks! `taxonomy-video_tag.php` - yes, I forgot about it :)